# Split and add digits

Tags: perl, math

If I open a file with strings like "233445", how can I then split that string into digits "2 3 3 4 4 5" and add each one to each other "2 + 3 + 3 etc..." and print out the result.

My code so far looks like this:

```
use strict;

#open (FILE, '<', shift);
#my @strings = <FILE>;
@strings = qw(12243434, 345, 676744); ## or a contents of a file
foreach my $numbers (@strings) {
   my @done = split(undef, $numbers);
   print "@done\n";
}
```

But I don't know where to start for the actual add function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = qw( 12243434 345 676744 );
for my $string (@strings) {
   my $sum;
   $sum += $_ for split(//, $string);
   print "$sum\n";
}
```

or

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw( sum );

my @strings = qw( 12243434 345 676744 );
for my $string (@strings) {
   my $sum = sum split(//, $string);
   print "$sum\n";
}
```

PS — Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have detected your misuse of commas in `qw`, and it would have dected your misuse of `undef` for [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)'s first argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
my @done;
#open (FILE, '<', shift);
#my @strings = <FILE>;
my @strings = qw(12243434, 345, 676744); ## or a contents of a file
foreach my $numbers (@strings) {
   @done = split(undef, $numbers);
   print "@done\n";
}   

my $tot;
map { $tot += $_} @done;
print $tot, "\n";
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add up the digits of each given number and not only from the last one?

Answer (score 2):

No one suggested an `eval` solution?

```
my @strings = qw( 12243434 345 676744 );
foreach my $string (@strings) {
    my $sum = eval join '+',split //, $string;
    print "$sum\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are in a file, a one-liner might be nice:

```
perl -lnwe 'my $sum; s/(\d)/$sum += $1/eg; print $sum' numbers.txt
```

Since addition only uses numbers, it is safe to ignore all other characters. So just extract them one at the time with the regex and sum them up.

TIMTOWTDI:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -lnwe 'print sum(/\d/g);' numbers.txt
perl -lnwe 'my $a; $a+=$_ for /\d/g; print $a' numbers.txt
```

Options:

- `-l` auto-chomp input and add newline to `print`
- `-n` implicit `while(<>)` loop around program -- open the file name given as argument and read each line into `$_`.